# I can't access a website without (Subdomain) typing "www." before it, need recommendation

Tags: internet-connection, domain, website, https, subdomain

I think my site has a problem as I can't access it without subdomain - typing "www" before it.

the only way I can access it is:

1. [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)
2. https:// www. mysite. com then it says "Your connection is not private" > Advanced > proceed to "my site"

any other way I get the error "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

Please recommend me the proper way of configuration - how it must be normally, and is it normal that it doesn't work without "www" ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you hosting your website? Which DNS service are you using (normally the one you bought your domain from)?

Comment: If you want your website to be reachable both with `www.` and without, this needs to be explicitly set up. Of course, in a web hosting control panel it may be as simple as clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't access my web site without typing `www` first.

"Naked" domains (e.g. `example.com`) must have a normal DNS A record set up to work correctly. Often, these are designated with the `@` symbol for the host in online DNS interfaces. Of course, your web server needs to be set up to respond to e.g. `example.com` as well (ex. with a correctly configured virtual host [Apache] or server block [nginx]).

> When I successfully connect to https://www.example.com, it tells me "Your connection is not private".

It sounds like you may have a self-signed SSL certificate securing your HTTPS connection. You should probably look into getting a recognized third-party SSL certificate from reputable certificate provider.

You can do this for free via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Unfortunately, Let's Encrypt doesn't provide SSL certificates directly, so you'll need to use another tool or service like [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to actually handle applying for, downloading and (in some cases) even installing a Let's Encrypt certificate. Note that you will need to renew this free SSL certificate every 90 days.

> Any other way, I get the error "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

This sounds like a web server configuration issue. As mentioned above, you should ensure that your web server is set up to recognize and respond to requests for e.g. `example.com`.

> Please recommend to me a proper configuration.

It could be possible to do this, but to have a chance, you would likely need to edit your question with additional details about how you are handling DNS for your domain and your web server setup.